# I can't deploy node js app to Ubuntu server

Tags: server, nginx, javascript

I had developed WebRTC real-time video conferencing app (N:1, N:N) and currently I am trying to deploy it to server.
But I can't set up Nginx successfully.

I used PM2 and I can't remove port number in app link.

If you have some idea about my issue, please help me.
Thanks.